# How can you find the nearest Arduino Yun

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

Imagine each office has an Arduino Yun and you only want to control the Arduino Yun that is closest to you (so in the same office that you are in). How can you find that Arduino Yun without specifying in which office you are?

In summary: I want to find the nearest Arduino Yun with my phone (preferably javascript).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a very specific question to a very broad question, how do you get the closest node connected to a network if you have no control over these nodes?

I guess you can't otherwise anyone would be able to get information on neighbours disregarding their privacy.

If you have control over the nodes then maybe you could use GPS location thoruhg a GPS module, or evaluate the IP for location, or estimate ping time? what do you mean by nearest?

Comment: Is there a technology available which sends out a signal and the phone can detect which signal is the strongest?

Comment: Your Android smartphone can evaluate the RSSI level of signal of the arduino YUN wifi interface.

Comment: Is this only possible when the arduino is in ad-hoc mode, or is it also possible when the arduino is connected to a router

Comment: This is not an Arduino Yun specific question and it's getting too specific. Maybe you should look for similar questions on wifi RSSI and ad-hoc mode, Arduino has little to do with it.